# error java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java, if-statement, inputmismatchexception

I am new to Java, and am trying to  make a program to see if a person has a normal temperature, not too low or too high.

I have been getting this error message:(when I'am input a double, not a int)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
        at ekstra217.main(ekstra217.java:15)
```

**Here is my code**

```
import java.util.*;

class temp
{//klassen start
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {//main start


    Scanner tast=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Write your temperatur!");
 //normal temperatur is between 36.5 and 37.5
    double temperatur=tast.nextDouble();
    if (temperatur<36.5)
    {
    System.out.println("Your temperatur is normal");
    } 
    else if(temperature>37.5)
    {//else if  starts
    System.out.println("You have over normal,you are sick");
    }//else if slutter

    else{
    System.out.println("You have normal temperature");
    }
}   
   }
```

Comment: What are you entering in standard input?

Comment: Your title is very misleading, i suggest you change it for something containing "java.util.InputMismatchException"

Comment: Remember that when specifying double-values, the comma-separator is '.' (dot) and not ',' (comma), like we are used to in Norway ;) This also applies to values specified through the command line.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're dead if you temperature is 5 or -293 Celsius :p

Comment: there will probably be other errors as you have `temperature` in some places and `temperatur` in others.

Comment: @RC No, then you'd be cryogenically frozen. All they'd have to do is thaw you out and you're good as new.

Answer (score 3):

You seems to be entering a `non-double` value as the input to your program and hence encountering `InputMismatchException` while executing:

```
tast.nextDouble();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to wrap your data reading into an `if` like this:

```
if (tast.hasNextDouble())
   tast.next.Double;
else {
   // print something and exit
   System.out.println("Incorrect temperature value!!!);
   System.exit(1);
   }
```